# Python simple tutorial variable not defined issue

Tags: python, pyaudio, pyttsx

So I was following a simple tutorial on youtube, and no matter what I do I keep getting the same issue.

Here is the code I used.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3


voices = []
engine = pyttsx3.init()

voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
for voice in voices:
    print(voice.id)
```

I am writing this in sublimeText3. Everytime I build this, I get the same error.

> File "C:\Users\This PC\Desktop\Py\introTest.py", line 14, in 
>       voices = engine.getProperty('voices') NameError: name 'engine' is not defined

Not sure why it is saying "engine" is not defined. I clearly have defined it under the try. Any help would be appreciated.

After removing the try/excepts I have a lot of new errors. Here is the build log.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\This
>   PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3__init__.py",
>   line 44, in init
>       eng = _activeEngines[driverName]   File "C:\Users\This PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\weakref.py", line
>   137, in **getitem**
>       o = self.datakey KeyError: None
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\This
>   PC\Desktop\Py\demo.py", line 7, in 
>       engine = pyttsx3.init()   File "C:\Users\This PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3__init__.py",
>   line 46, in init
>       eng = Engine(driverName, debug)   File "C:\Users\This PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\engine.py",
>   line 52, in **init**
>       self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)   File "C:\Users\This
>   PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\driver.py",
>   line 75, in **init**
>       self._module = importlib.import_module(name)   File "C:\Users\This PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib__init__.py",
>   line 127, in import_module
>       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import   File
>   "", line 983, in _find_and_load   File
>   "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked 
>   File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
>   File "", line 728, in
>   exec_module   File "", line 219, in
>   _call_with_frames_removed   File "C:\Users\This PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py",
>   line 3, in 
>       import win32com.client ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32com' [Finished in 0.1s]

Comment: Before the error occurs, does your code print "Import Issue" or "Runtime Issue"?

Comment: if your try statement fails, there is no engine. try declaring engine=None below voices

Comment: `engine` doesn't exist if your `try` fails

Comment: That is the entire error log it does not print import or runtime issue.

Comment: @ScottSkiles I added that, now the attrib error is "NoneType" object has no attribute 'getProperty'

Comment: Ohh that being said, if engine is failing that means that pyttsx3 is not initializing right?

Comment: I suggest that you remove all `try/except` things, let the program fail, and post the actual error message. Perhaps it will explain why the engine fails to initialize.

Comment: @DYZ Ok, I am going to update my code, after removing the try/excepts I have a ton of no errors. I will show.

Comment: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32com'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try input the import in the try/catch block , and check if you got undefined after import, so throw exception.
Looking in module official website, look your console logs for some of this erros,

Fixes for possible errors :

`No module named win32com.client
No module named win32
No module named win32api`

and try this

`pip install pypiwin32`

Addtiional show your logs to we understand better the situation!

Comment: This has nothing to do with the issue. I'm not sure where you picked those errors from?

Comment: I installed pypiwin32 and it solved the issue. It now displays the voices. Thanks @jefferson

Comment: @roganjosh you see, i look he is using python on windows, so i deduced he need more than usual pypiwin libs. Long time programming :D

Comment: @JeffersonPuchalski how do I install pypiwin32 with conda though?

Comment: Activate the environment where you want to put the program. ex source env/bin/bash, Use pip or Anaconda prompt to install the pypiwin32
And ty import in python console or Anaconda prompt.

Answer (score 1):

After seeing your full error log dump (without the `try` block hiding errors), in the last bit is the text:

`line 3, in import win32com.client ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32com' [Finished in 0.1s]`

I would suggest looking at [Jefferson Puchalski's answer again](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51993712/8189007). (hint: it's telling you you're missing a module that `pyttsx3` is dependant on)

---

You are attempting to assign `engine = pyttsx3.init()`, but when/if it fails, you then declare `voices = engine.getProperty('voices')`. But as the `try` block has failed, `engine` has not been declared.

Below, I assign `engine = None`, and skip the `else` form the `try` block; instead using a conditional to determine if it's `None` or not (it worked correctly on creating `engine`).

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3


voices = []
engine = None

try:
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
except ImportError:
    print('Import Issue')
except RuntimeError:
    print('Runtime Issue')

if (engine is not None):
    voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
    for voice in voices:
        print(voice.id)
else:
    print("Something went wrong")
```

Comment: Ok, after using your code. My build responds with the following

Answer (score 0):

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3

voices = [] 
try:
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
except ImportError:
    print('Requested driver is not found')
    engine = None
except RuntimeError:
    print('Driver fails to initialize')
    engine = None

if engine is None:
    print('Something went wrong')

else:
    voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
    for voice in voices:
        print(voice.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

on Ubuntu I had the same issue. Easiest fix, ever:

`sudo apt install libespeak1`

Answer (score 0):

Hi I've faced a similar issue and this is how i managed to change voice with ease

```
import pyttsx3

voices = []

eng = pyttsx3.init()

voices = eng.getProperty('voice')

eng.setProperty('voice',voices[1].id)
eng.say("Some text here")
eng.runAndWait()
```